# How to create azimuth raster layer by pyqgis?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, point, azimuth

I want to create an azimuth raster layer base of single point shapefile, for this I write below code that create a memory point layer that each point in memory layer is center of each pixel and have a field by name of "Azimuth", in qgis when run this program it's ok, but when I want to load created raster layer "Azimuth_lyr.tif", display this message:

[image]

What is error(s) in this code?

my code:

```
def azimuth_raster(self):
    # Chosen Point layer with GDAL
    pnt_layer = self.dlg.ui.comboBox_sourcelayer.currentIndex()
    pntId = self.dlg.ui.comboBox_sourcelayer.itemData(pnt_layer)
    pntLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(pntId)
    feat = pntLayer.getFeatures().next()
    pntxy = feat.geometry().asPoint()

    def pixel2coord(x, y):
        """Returns global coordinates from pixel x, y coords"""
        xp = (g_pixelWidth * x) + g_originX + (g_pixelWidth/2)
        yp = (g_pixelHeight * y) + g_originY + (g_pixelHeight /2)
        return(xp, yp)

    # Open tif file
    ds = QgsRasterLayer("C:\Temp_NoiseOnePoint\prox_Distance.tif","prox_Distance")
    global g_pixelWidth, g_pixelHeight
    g_pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
    g_pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

    # extent of the layer
    ext = ds.extent()
    global g_originX ,g_originY
    g_originX ,g_originY = (ext.xMinimum(),ext.yMinimum())
    cols = ds.width()
    rows = ds.height()

    #Create temporary vector layer and add to map
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=", "temporary_points", "memory")
    vl.dataProvider().addAttributes([ QgsField("X_coord", QVariant.Int),
                                      QgsField("Y_coord", QVariant.Int),
                                      QgsField("Azimuth", QVariant.Int) ])
    fet = QgsFeature()
    for row in range(0,rows):
        for col in range(0,cols):
            rspnt = pixel2coord(col,row)
            fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1])))
            fet.initAttributes(3)
            fet.setAttribute(0, rspnt[0] )
            fet.setAttribute(1, rspnt[1])
            az = pntxy.azimuth(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1]))
            if az < 0.0:
                azim = 360 + az
            else:
                azim = az
            fet.setAttribute(2, azim)
            vl.dataProvider().addFeatures( [fet] )
            vl.updateExtents()
            vl.updateFields()

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vl])

    # Convert azimuth point layer to azimuth raster layer

    mem_layer_provider = vl.dataProvider()

    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromWkt(vl.crs().toWkt())
    out_rst = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create("C:\Temp_NoiseOnePoint\Azimuth_lyr.tif",
                                                   cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    out_rst.SetGeoTransform(g_x_min, g_pixelWidth, 0, g_y_max, 0, -g_pixelHeight)
    out_rst.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    band_rst = out_rst.GetRasterBand(1)
    band_rst.SetNoDataValue(g_NoData_value)
    band_rst.FlushCache()

    gdal.RasterizeLayer(out_rst, [1], mem_layer_provider, options = ["ATTRIBUTE=Azimuth"])

    # close bands
    band_rst = None

    # close rasters
    out_rst = None
```

Comment: Might not solve your problem but when it comes to setting paths, I always use double slashes for the final directory to where the file is stored (e.g. `ds = QgsRasterLayer("C:/Temp_NoiseOnePoint//prox_Distance.tif","prox_Distance")` and `"C:/Temp_NoiseOnePoint//Azimuth_lyr.tif"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably could be here:

```
.
.
.
    out_rst.SetGeoTransform(g_x_min, g_pixelWidth, 0, g_y_max, 0, -g_pixelHeight)
.
.
.
```

because 'SetGeoTransform' method needs a list as parameter.

Try out this:

```
.
.
.
    out_rst.SetGeoTransform( [ g_x_min, g_pixelWidth, 0, g_y_max, 0, -g_pixelHeight ] )
.
.
.
```

I hope that it helps

**Editing Note:**

I tried to solve this 'gdal.RasterizeLayer' issue unsuccessfully. So, I used another approach: the **gdal_rasterize** command. The code was:

```
import os

mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

extent = layers[0].extent() #vector layer

xmin = extent.xMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()

xsize = 73.9887232281
ysize = 73.9887232281

vlayer = layers[0]  #vector layer
vprovider = vlayer.dataProvider()
uri = vprovider.dataSourceUri()

uri = uri.split("|")

(root, filename) = os.path.split(uri[0])

filename = filename[:-4]

#extent of raster
extent = "-te " + str(xmin) + " " + str(ymin) + " " + str(xmax) + " " + str(ymax) + " "

#resolution of raster
resolution = " -tr " + str(xsize) + " " +  str(ysize) + " "

attribute_name = " -a id "

input_vector_line = " -l " + filename + " " + uri[0]
output_raster = " /home/zeito/pyqgis_data/random_points.tif"

cmd = "gdal_rasterize -at " + \
                     extent + \
                 resolution + \
          input_vector_line + \
             attribute_name + \
              output_raster

print cmd

os.system(cmd)
```

I tested the script with this shapefile (it will be rasterized by id field):

[image]

After running the script the result was successfully. It could be corroborated at the next image where I 'zoom in' on point with id = 23.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  It's good suggestion and work but in raster layer "Azimuth_lyr.tif" created all pixels have zero value no "Azimuth" values from memory layer!! why?

Comment: I think that the problem is now here: `gdal.RasterizeLayer(out_rst, [1], mem_layer_provider, options = ["ATTRIBUTE=Azimuth"])`

Comment: That's right, problem is in "mem_layer_provider", I don't know how get memory layer, I think "mem_layer_provider = vl.dataProvider()
" is not correct method to get memory layer.

Comment: Your memory layer is **vl**. The **mem_layer_provider** is an object of **QgsVectorDataProvider**.

Comment: sorry, that's right, but when I use vl in "gdal.RasterizeLayer", raster layer created but all pixel values is zero (0)!!!!

Comment: I used another approach, the 'gdal_rasterize' command, and it worked.

Comment: It's ok,thanks, but I used "QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat" to convert memory layer to shape then use the shape in gdal.RasterizeLayer, I don't know my approach is optimize or your approach!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34970/discussion-between-h-madadi-and-xunilk).